# Need assistance with SUMIFS or another formula to replace SUMPRODUCT in spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need a formula that is faster at counting occurrences between dates.

I have 2 columns, one has a date (Date incident occurred) and another is the incident type. Basically I want to be able to add all the incidents of "suspicious" that took place in jan, feb, mar etc. I have other categories as well, but I can just substitute when needed.

Currently I am using SUMPRODUCT, which is extremely slow and making data entry slow. I have attempted SUMIFS, but am not sure how to get it to work.

Thanks

Comment: SUMPRODUCT, as the name says, tries to calculate a product and then sum it all, which is something that you don't want. @Aaron referred COUNTIF would work for your situation but it isn't clear (from the [online docs](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countif-HP005209029.aspx)) how to use another cell reference.

Answer (score 1):

For multi-conditional counting **COUNTIFS** (with an "S" on the end) should fit the bill if you are using excel 2007 or later.

For example if your date column is A and incident type column is B then you can use a formula like this in E2

`=COUNTIFS(B:B,"suspicious",A:A,">="&D2,A:A,"<"&EOMONTH(D2,0)+1)`

where D2 contains a date - 1st of the month in which you want to count.

You can list more dates in D3 down and then just copy the formula down the column to get a count for each month

Comment: Thanks a ton for the COUNTIFS help, that actually solved my issue. I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

COUNTIF might be a better solution, rather than SUMPRODUCT.

Also, since you said data entry was becoming slow, you could try using a macro, rather than a worksheet formula. That way the calculation is only ran when you need it, not automatically every time the sheet is modified.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will check out COUNTIF and macros.

Comment: I'm convinced a good way to learn is by playing - you might try setting up some dummy values in a spreadsheet and play around some to see what works best.